# How can I add buttons to a file icon in the Finder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

How can I add a button to a file icon in the Finder, like those for PDF files?

See the arrow buttons in this picture:

[image: QuickLook PDF Preview]

Answer (score 2):

The buttons are generated by a QuickLook plug-in. To get an interactive preview like this, you will need to create a [QuickLook plug-in for your app](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

You will need to use the HTML preview type and generate HTML that contains buttons and images yourself.